# External Libraries Errors When Building Android APK File

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, libraries

I'm using an external library in my gradle file.

```
implementation group: 'org.samba.jcifs', name: 'jcifs', version: '1.3.3'
```

When I run the application works just fine. But when I build the apk file is giving me errors, that it can not find reference to other classes. I am also using "Proguard" in my android gradle so I can minify my app as much as possible. When I try to build the app it gives me this errors. None of these classes I'm using in my project. then one that I use I don't see it listed here. I wonder if this error, is telling me to delete these classes so my final apk file is smaller.

```
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.Filter  
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpServletRequest: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced method 'java.util.Enumeration getInitParameterNames()' in program class jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer    
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getInitParameter(java.lang.String)' in program class jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletException  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterConfig   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterChain    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.Filter 
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletException   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterConfig   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterChain    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterConfig   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletRequest 
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletResponse    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterChain    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletRequest 
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletResponse    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterChain    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest    
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.FilterConfig   
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpServletRequest: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper 
jcifs.http.NtlmHttpServletRequest: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest    
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletConfig 
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletException  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletConfig 
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletConfig 
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession  
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletException  
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest   
jcifs.http.NtlmSsp: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
there were 137 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.  
there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.    
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: try: -dontwarn javax.naming.**
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**

Comment: ok.. I added your settings to proguard file. now I'm getting a lot less errors only 3. but still getting some errors when building apk. This is first time using progaurd file and configuration.

Comment: I'm getting this errors. jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced method 'java.util.Enumeration getInitParameterNames()' in program class jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer 
jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getInitParameter(java.lang.String)' in program class jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer 
there were 2 unresolved references to program class members. 
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: I'm getting build failed: build failed 15 s 282 ms
Run build 15 s 65 ms
Load build 4 ms
Configure build 1 s 456 ms
Calculate task graph 178 ms
Run tasks 13 s 419 ms
:app:preBuild 1 ms
:app:extractProguardFiles 7 ms
:app:preReleaseBuild 531 ms